# Spring-boot gradle project creating empty webapp folder after building war

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, war

I have a spring boot gradle project with a server module and I am using the gradle war plugin in my build.gradle file.

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/web_project_tutorial.html

Per this link: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html (80.1)

I am overriding the configure method and I can see that a war file is being built and placed in the server/build/tmp directory.

When the project builds it also creates a empty webapp directory at server/src/main/webapp (this is the default webAppDirName).

http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/gradle/getting-started-with-gradle-creating-a-web-application-project/

The war is needed so that our ops guys can run it on an external Tomcat container. However, for convenience, us devs are just building and running with the gradle wrapper > ./gradlew :server:bootRun using the embedded Tomcat container.

My problem is that when we do a bootRun it is looking at the empty webapp folder that gets created during the build process and throwing this error:

```
2016-02-23 10:51:32.632  INFO 83043 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 22443 (https)
2016-02-23 10:51:32.641  INFO 83043 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-02-23 10:51:32.642  INFO 83043 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.30
2016-02-23 10:51:32.673 ERROR 83043 --- [cat-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase   : A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/imageretriever]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:916) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_60]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Tomcat].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/imageretriever]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@7f31763e]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.c.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4928) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5058) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified [/Users/carlc/intellij_workspace/image-retriever/src/main/webapp] is not valid
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.createMainResourceSet(StandardRoot.java:723) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:684) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.0.30.jar:8.0.30]
    ... 9 common frames omitted
```

I thought the issue might be tangentially related to this: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/1313

But I wasn't able to glean any helpful information out of it.

I can think of two solutions: 1) remove the offending webapp folder during the build process 2) Configure bootRun to ignore the webapp folder all together 3) Your suggestions go here _____________ :)

I can post the build.gradle or other code you think relevant upon request. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you post the complete error? It's not clear from what you have posted that it's related to the empty `src/main/webapp` folder

Comment: I edited the question to contain more of the error. I know it's failing because the webapp folder is present and once I delete it the app will run as expected. I am really more concerned with how I can stop the gradle war plugin from creating it so that when I do a bootRun the error will no longer occur. Thanks!

Comment: As far as I can tell, Gradle doesn't create an empty `src/main/webapp` folder. Also, looking at `StandardRoot.createMainResourceSet`, it won't fail if that directory is empty. Can you share a sample project that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I believe it's the war plugin that is creating that folder:

http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/gradle/getting-started-with-gradle-creating-a-web-application-project/.

Comment: That links says "Even though the War plugin adds the src/main/webapp directory to the project’s directory layout, it does not create it. If we need that directory, we have to create it ourself."

Comment: You are right. I didn't read it closely enough. I have no idea what is creating that directory then..

Comment: Ok so this is the behavior I am seeing. If I delete the webapp folder from the server module (server/src/main/webapp) and then close intellij, when I re open intellij it will throw an error saying "Module 'server' already exists in the project."

Then if I do a gradle refresh: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/synchronizing-changes-in-gradle-project-and-intellij-idea-project.html

It rebuilds the project and re indexes everything. It's at this point when the webapp folder is created.

Comment: It's definitely the war plugin which is creating that webapp directory. If I comment that out of my build.gradle it no longer gets generated.

Comment: Although the folder isn't created when I run: gradle war assembe, somehow it is being created when intellij calls the gradle tooling api..